# Incorrect expansion of a function-like macro

Tags: c, macros, declaration

I have a problem with macros. I am supposed to come up with a macro `ENTRY`, that puts a value into an array ( `scanf("%d",&ENTRY(x,i))` was given).

I tried: `#define ENTRY (a,b) (a[b-1])`, but that didn't work.
It created a compiler error that says, that a and b are undeclared.
But I thought that I don't have to declare variables used in macros, especially because, for example: `#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))` worked in another program.

So what am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
#define ENTRY (a,b) (a[b-1])

int main(void)
{
    
    int x[N],i;
    float y[N];

    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){ printf("x_%d = ",i);scanf("%d",&ENTRY(x,i));}
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){ printf("y_%d = ",i);scanf("%lf",&ENTRY(y,i));}

    return 0
}
```

Comment: Is the problem to define this macro, or is this a problem you're trying to solve *with* the macro? C arrays are zero-indexed. The need for` ENTRY` goes away if you just accept that.

Comment: Why was this question marked as off-topic?

Comment: I don't know if this was a genuine typo, but it might not be, given that elsewhere in C and the preprocessor, whitespace is insignificant. Was it a typo, @vincent.perl99?

Answer (score 8):

Function-like macro definitions can't have [whitespace](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10) after the macro name

```
#define ENTRY (a,b) (a[b-1])              // wrong
```

=>

```
#define ENTRY(a,b) ((a)[(b)-1])               // correct
```

[6.10 – Preprocessing directives](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10):

> ...
>
> control-line:
>   ...
>
> `# define` *identifier* *lparen* *identifier-listopt* `)` *replacement-list new-line*
>    `# define` *identifier* *lparen* `... )` *replacement-list* *new-line*
>    `# define` *identifier* *lparen* *identifier-list* `, ... )` *replacement-list* *new-line*
>
> ...
>
> lparen:
>      a `(` character not immediately preceded by white-space

With the space, you get an object-like macro that expands to `(a,b) (a[b-1])`.

(For additional robustness, it's also recommended to parenthesize the parameters so that it also works if you pass in more complex expressions.)

Comment: Should even be `(a[(b)-1])` to be thorough.

Comment: @M.M Even better, yes.

Comment: And this is the reason why the C standard syntax is written in such a peculiar manner: `# define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line`. They defined an item _lparen_ for the left brace, whereas the right brace is simply listed as `)`. Looking at the definition for _lparen_ in turn, it is: "a `(` character not immediately preceded by white-space".

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. I had hyperlinked this part of the standard but I have now included it in the answer as well so it's easier to see.